# Processo Ativo quando fecho o programa C# WPF

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação em C# ela funciona normalmente, porém quando eu clico no botão para fechar, ela fecha mas ela não para ... acho que fica em alguma especie de segundo plano, ou seja seu processo permanece ativo! e só é finalizado quando eu clico no Stop do visual studio. Existe algum meio de finalizar esse processo quando eu clico no botão para fechar, e porque será está ocorrendo esse erro?

Quando o usuário executa o programa ele abre uma tela de login! caso a empresa não esteja cadastrada ele esconde a tela de login e abre a tela da empresa! 
caso a empresa esteja cadastrada ele esconde a tela de login e abre o menu!
será que o problema seria com relação ao esconder a tela login? segue exemplo do código

```
  public Login()
  {
     Inicia();
  }

 private void Inicia() {


      bool ValidaEmpresa = new ConEmpresa().JaEstaCadastrada();
      // Se ValidaEmpresa for true é porque já esta cadastrada!
      if (ValidaEmpresa)
      {
          // Carrega o menu 
          MenuADM frm = new MenuADM();

          this.Hide();

          frm.ShowDialog();
          this.Close();
       }
       else
       {
           Empresa frm = new Empresa(true);
           this.Hide();
           frm.ShowDialog();
           // Apos cadastrar a empresa abre o menu
           MenuADM frm = new MenuADM();
           frm.ShowDialog();
           this.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você mesmo respondeu qual é o problema, a tela inicial nunca é fechada.

O certo é você fazer este controle de fluxo noutra classe (talvez na classe `App`, que é quem faz a inicialização da aplicação) e, ao invés de esconder, é preciso **fechar o form**. Apenas escondendo, ele ainda estará disponível e a aplicação ainda estará rodando.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        loginWindow.Show();

        bool ValidaEmpresa = new ConEmpresa().JaEstaCadastrada();

        if (ValidaEmpresa)
        {
          // Carrega o menu 
          MenuADM frm = new MenuADM();

          loginWindow.Close();

          frm.ShowDialog();
          this.Close();
       }
       else
       {
           Empresa frm = new Empresa(true);
           this.Hide();
           frm.ShowDialog();

           MenuADM frm = new MenuADM();
           frm.ShowDialog();
           loginWindow.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um meio encontrado que consegui realizar isso foi ao invés de chamar da forma atual alternar a chamada utilizando o App.Current, segue o exemplo:

```
 App.Current.MainWindow = new MenuADM();
 App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
 this.Close();
```